# Calculate a 3d camera matrix

Tags: java, 3d

this is homework, but I've been trying for ours and I just don't get what I do wrong. The idea is to create a camera from three given vectors, the center (camera position) the up (world up, this one is (0, 1, 0)) and the lookAt (which is the point in world coordinates to look at).

Everythinig is working fine when I move the camera on the x and z axis, however when I move it on the y axis (up / down).. it just does not keep looking at (0, 0, 0).

I've got the following code, Vector3f and Matrix4f are from javax.vecmath.*

```
private void updateCameraMatrix() {
    Vector3f z = new Vector3f();
    z.sub(center, lookAt);
    z.normalize();

    Vector3f x = new Vector3f();
    x.cross(z, up);
    x.normalize();

    Vector3f y = new Vector3f();
    y.cross(x, z);
    y.normalize();



    cameraMatrix.set(new float[] {
        x.x, y.x, z.x, 0.0f,
        x.y, y.y, z.y, 0.0f,
        x.z, y.z, z.z, 0.0f,
        0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f
    });

    cameraMatrix.mul(new Matrix4f(new float[] {
        1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, -center.x,
        0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, -center.y,
        0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, -center.z,
        0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f
    }));
}
```

Thank you for any help in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand why you calculated `x, y, z,` the way that you do. Though to calculate a 4x4 Matrix and apply a Camera Look At to it, then I would do it like this:

```
public final Matrix4 lookAt(Vector3 eye, Vector3 center)
{
    float dx = eye.x - center.x;
    float dy = eye.y - center.y;
    float dz = eye.z - center.z;

    float pitch = (float) Math.atan2(dy, Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dz * dz));
    float yaw = (float) Math.atan2(dz, dx);

    pitch = -pitch;
    yaw = yaw - 1.57079633f;

    Matrix4 camera_matrix = new Matrix4();

    matrix.identity();

    matrix.rotate(pitch, -1f, 0f, 0f);
    matrix.rotate(yaw, 0f, 1f, 0f);

    matrix.translate(-eyex, -eyey, -eyez);

    return matrix;
}
```

The function here by default "uses" an `up` which is `(0, 1, 0)`.

*As you can see I write `Vector3`, `Matrix4` and not `Vector3f`, `Matrix4f` that is because I don't use the `javax.vecmath.*` classes. I've made custom classes for calculating the following, though it is basically the same, and vecmath probably/should contain the same methods which I use. Though if it doesn't write it as a comment and I can provide them as well.*

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works like a charm. I was trying to implement the formulas from a lecture slide... ;-).

Comment: Any idea what the javax.vecmath equivalent of the matrix.rotate(...) calls would be?  Also, I'm assuming the variable "camera_matrix" above is actually supposed to be "matrix".